# Creating a pointer within a class to another object

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

May someone please help me correct the following. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to create a pointer to an existing object within a new object. I can't get the syntax correct and keep getting errors.

Here's my code:

```
class Country
{
    string name; 
public:
    Country (string name)
    {   name = name; 
        cout << "Country has been created" << endl;}

    ~Country()
    {cout << "Country destroyed \n";}

};

class Person
{
    //string name;
    //Date dateOfBirth;
    Country *pCountry; 

public:
    Person(Country *c):
      pCountry(c)
      {}

};




int main()
{
    Country US("United States");
    Person(&US)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to include what error(s) you get?

Comment: Stop, take a breath and think on how silly this looks.`name = name;`

Comment: You're missing a name for your person variable, and a semicolon following its declaration - other than that, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget in your main.cpp?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

you also need a semicolon in your main:

```
int main()
{
    Country US("United States");
    Person person(&US); // < -- variable name and semicolon missing

    return 0;
}
```

You should also change:

```
Country (string name)
{
   this->name = name; // <--  assign name to member variable
   ...
```

or better, use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Country (string name) : name(name) // <--  assign name to member variable
{
   ...
```

And in general you should try to be consistent with the way you format your code.